# Css / Pseudo element ::before behind his container not work

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I try to do something but it's not working at all.
That looks pretty simple, i desire to add a `:before` to an element with a background, but each time i do that, the `::before` goes in front of the container.

```
    .container{
     position:relative;
     z-index:1;
     background:blue;
     border:1 px solid white;
   }

   .container::before{
      position:absolute;
      content:"";
      z-index:-1;
      top:-10px;
      left:-10px;
      width:calc(100% + 20px);
      height:calc(100% + 20px);
      background:red;
   }
```

Comment: Where do you want the ::before to go? To the left, the right, or behind container?

Comment: Behind the container..I simplify the code but the before have a gradient i wanna put behind it, that's why he's in position top -10px , left -10px of his container ( and the calc too )

Answer (score 2):

Simply remove the `z-index:1` property from the `.container`

```css
body {
 background-color: #eee;
}

.container{
 position:relative;
 background:blue;
 border:1 px solid white;

 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
}

.container::before{
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  z-index:-1;
  top:-10px;
  left:-10px;
  width:calc(100% + 20px);
  height:calc(100% + 20px);
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="container"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) sounds logic yes..But if ( it's my case for exemple ), the body have a background, you agree that my before will goes behind the body, right ? That's mean i need to have another container parent to this one with a z-index superior to the body ?

Comment: I just updated my answer. As you will see, the body has a grey background :)

Comment: Sorry I thought I had post this last answer yersteday, but I didn't... So, here is a complete article about z-index and stack contextualization, because it could be more complex than it appear to : https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Plus, don't forget to set this question to solve if it is :)